# Lists being Overwritten?

Tags: python, list, overwrite

I created a user-defined instruction 'getSetpoints' that reads a group of data via serial and automatically chops it up into 4-digit pieces that get dumped into a list called GROUP# (the # depends on which group of data the user wants).

All of this works great, and I am able to print this data in the Python shell simply by typing GROUP0, GROUP1, GROUP2, etc. AFTER running the getSetpoints() function, so I know it is being stored correctly.

However, now I want to automatically load each member in my GROUP0 list into its properly named variable (ie. Lang_Style is GROUP0[0], CTinv_Sign is GROUP0[1], etc.).  I created decodeSP() to do this which I call at the end of getSetpoints().

The only issue is, when I type Lang_Style (or any other of my named variables) in the python shell after running getSetpoints(), it just returns a 0.  See code below.  I've included the output of my Python shell as well.

I just don't understand how GROUP0 keeps its data after the user-defined instruction executes, but the other variables get set back to zero every time.  It is identical as far as I can see.

```
# Define Variables (This is shortened to only show one GROUP...)
GROUP0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Lang_Style = 0
CTinv_Sign = 0
Freq = 0
PT_Ratio = 0
CT_Ratio = 0
DST = 0
System_Volts = 0
Gen_Phase = 0
Op_Mode = 0
Seq_Pref = 0
Re_Commit = 0
Bit_Address = 0

CRLF = bytearray ([0x0D, 0x0A])
RESULTS = [GROUP0, GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3, GROUP4, GROUP5]

def getSetpoints(group):
    if 0 <= group <= 5:
        # Send out the command for Display Setpoint, then group number, then CRLF.
        s = serial.Serial('COM1', '9600') # serial port, baud rate
        s.write("DP")
        s.write(group)
        s.write(CRLF)
        temp = s.read(len(RESULTS[group])*6) # Each setpoint is 6 characters (space + x + 4 digits).
        n = 0
        for n in range(len(RESULTS[group])):
            # RESULTS[group][n] = int(temp[2+n*6:6+n*6],16) # Use this one if you want Integers
            RESULTS[group][n] = temp[2+n*6:6+n*6] # Cut out the space and the x, leaving only the 4 digits.
        print RESULTS[group] # Debug Print
        s.close()
        decodeSP()
        return
    else:
        print 'Invalid Group Number'
        return

def decodeSP():
    Lang_Style = GROUP0[0]
    CTinv_Sign = GROUP0[1]
    Freq = GROUP0[2]
    PT_Ratio = GROUP0[3]
    CT_Ratio = GROUP0[4]
    DST = GROUP0[5]
    System_Volts = GROUP0[6]
    Gen_Phase = GROUP0[7]
    Op_Mode = GROUP0[8]
    Seq_Pref = GROUP0[9]
    Re_Commit = GROUP0[10]
    Bit_Address = GROUP0[11]
return
```

Python Shell Ouput:

```
================================ RESTART ================================
getSetpoints(0) 
['0004', '0000', '003C', '0000', '00C8', '0001', '0078', '0101', '0000', '0003', '0001', '0001']
GROUP0
['0004', '0000', '003C', '0000', '00C8', '0001', '0078', '0101', '0000', '0003', '0001', '0001']
Lang_Style
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the difference between changing an object's value and calling a method on it:

when you do

```
RESULTS[group][n] = temp[2+n*6:6+n*6]
```

you actually call a method (`__setitem__`) on RESULTS.  The above instruction expands to:

```
RESULTS.__getitem__(group).__setitem__(n, temp.__getslice__(2+n*6, 6+n*6))
```

you do not explicitly change `RESULTS`, you simply call methods on it and it's up to the object to modify itself.

Instead, when you do

```
Lang_Style = GROUP0[0]
```

you **set** `Lang_Style` to `GROUP0[0].

This doesn't completely answer the question, though.  Your question is: why doesn't it stick ?  Well, Python can get the values from upper namespaces (e.g. the global namespace from within the `decodeSP` function) but it will not overwrite them.

You can change that by specifying, at the beginning of `decodeSP` which objects should be considered global.  See http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement

e.g.

```
def decodeSP():
    global Lang_Style, CTinv_Sign, ...
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you for the explanation of the difference between the two. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you use it, all the variables in `decodeSP` are declared as local. You want to write to a global, so you need to make a reference to the global within function scope. Use `global` keyword to achieve that:

```
def decodeSP():
    global Lang_Style
    global CTinv_Sign 
    global Freq
    # ...
    Lang_Style = GROUP0[0]
    CTinv_Sign = GROUP0[1]
    Freq = GROUP0[2]
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `decodeSP` creates a lot of local variables with the same names as the outer variables. Since you don't return anything, all those changes are lost. You would have to declare all those variables `global` to effect the outer scope.

Considering the resulting amount of repetition, another options is using `namedtuple` from the `collections` module

```
from collections import namedtuple
data = namedtuple('data', 'Lang_Style, CTinv_Sign, Freq, PT_Ratio, CT_Ratio, DST, System_Volts, Gen_Phase, Op_Mode, Seq_Pref, Re_Commit, Bit_Address')

parsed_data = data(*GROUP0)  #  need to fill in the array as params
```

You can then access the data as

```
print parsed_data.Lang_Style
```

Comment: True, but I don't see how 

`code`RESULTS[group][n] = temp[2+n*6:6+n*6] # Cut out the space and the x, leaving only the 4 digits


is any different than declaring them locally like i do in decodeSP(), yet GLOBAL0 acts as though it is global already.

Comment: EDIT: deubeuliou answered this question above for me.  If you can't tell...I just started Python this week hah...

Comment: That line reads from `RESULT`, markedly it gets the group'th element. Then you modify this return value, by setting one array entry after the other in the loop